# how to use excel exported file in C# project

Tags: c#, include, text-files

I have a txt file which I export from excel and I want to include it in my project.
This file may change later when i export again from excel.

How do I include it in my folder and in the build and also make sure it will reflect any change to it when i export again from excel?

Comment: When Excel overwrites the file used in the build, the new version will of course be used in the next local build. Or are you asking how to check in into a version control system?

Comment: i want to know how to make VS include this file in the project and how to access in my code. i tried to "add an existing" file but when i exported the file again the file i added did not change.

Comment: Add existing item will by default copy the file to the source directory. Either overwrite this copy when exporting from excel, or use "Add as Link" in the Add existing item dialog.

Comment: and which is a better approach? use a link or overwrite externally? how do i make sure it is part of my build and how do i read this file in my code?

Comment: Best approach is add as existing item which will copy to bin folder and if yoiiu change type of project (like debug and release) will copy to correct folder.  But with some file types you have to change settings to automatically do the copy.  So after doing the Add Existing you should right click in Solution Explorer the ICON and select the copy option if not already set.

Comment: thanks. now this is not related and should go on a different question still, why is it that when i read the text file, which has spaces, the spaces are show as "?"